# How to get any table last id using SQL?

Tags: php, html, sql

I need last test(table) id.
If I use (in SQL) `'SELECT MAX(id) FROM test`, then show the last `id`.
But when I use that in my model, showing error.

**Codes from model (Test_model):**

```php
function get_test_table_last_id() {
    $test_table = $this->db->dbprefix('test');

    $sql = "SELECT MAX($test_table.id) AS last_id FROM $test_table";

    return $this->db->query($sql)->row()->last_id;
}
```

**Codes from controller (Test controller):**

```php
$model_info = $this->Test_model->get_test_table_last_id()->last_id;
$view_data["last_id"] = $model_info;

$this->load->view("test_view/view", $view_data);
```

**Codes from view (test_view):**

```php
<?php echo $last_id ?>
```

I'm getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return an array like this one:

function get_test_table_last_id() {

```
$test_table = $this->db->dbprefix('test');

$sql = "SELECT MAX($test_table.id) AS last_id FROM $test_table";

return $this->db->query($sql)->row_array();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In your function `get_test_table_last_id()`, you return the `last_id` value of the query...

```
return $this->db->query($sql)->row()->last_id;
//                                   ^^^^^^^^
```

and then you try and use...

```
$model_info = $this->Test_model->get_test_table_last_id()->last_id;
//                                                        ^^^^^^^^
```

So this is trying to get the `last_id` again.  Just use the return value as it is...

```
$model_info = $this->Test_model->get_test_table_last_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT MAX(ID) AS last_id FROM `table`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `->last_id` from as described.

Codes from controller (Test controller):

```
// $model_info = $this->Test_model->get_test_table_last_id()->last_id;
$model_info = $this->Test_model->get_test_table_last_id();
$view_data["last_id"] = $model_info;

$this->load->view("test_view/view", $view_data);
```